# Left-pointing-double replaced by less-than after saved to database

Tags: c#, oracle11g, entity-framework-5

I'm reading some text files and saving them into database, but all the « are being replaced by < after save. Why is that? Same thing also happen to the » and > counter parts.

When I read the text file, I just used:

```
var txt = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

When I save, I just assign the `txt` to a string property and call `SaveChanges`. The property is mapped to a `CLOB` column.

```
«
Left-pointing double angle quotation mark
Unicode number: U+00AB
HTML-code: &#171;

»
Less-than sign
Unicode number: U+003C
HTML-code: &#60;
```